# Apollo server is very slow even with light queries

Tags: express, graphql, apollo-server

I know that GraphQL can get slower with large data sets, but what I have is an array of around 60 items. E.g. in a simple query, I fetch, the `id`, `title` and `country` and it takes more than 3 ms on average for the Apollo server to return data while the resolver reruns data calling a REST endpoint in less than 200ms. I use Apollo studio to debug queries and what I get does not help me at all - everywhere less than 1 ms.

[image]

If I go for a more complex query with 2 nested queries, it take 15-20 seconds for the same 60 items and the nested queries are quite light.

I googled and found that people face similar issues with really heavy queries with thousands of items and they talk about a few seconds, not 15-20 seconds.

Feels like there is something wrong in my setup. I do not get any errors.
I am using `apollo-server-express` with a basic setup:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  introspection: true,
  playground: !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'),
  engine: {
    reportSchema: true,
    graphVariant: 'current',
  },
  subscriptions: {
    onConnect: () => winston.info('Connected to websocket'),
    onDisconnect: webSocket => winston.info(`Disconnected from websocket ${webSocket}`),
  },
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    //eslint-disable-line
    req,
    pubSub,
  }),
});
```

Comment: having the same issue. I am also using Apollo Studio for monitoring. Can you try to disable apollo studio and manually check if its better? I feel like apollo studio monitoring is slowing down the apollo server performance.

Comment: @Dude I tried without it as well. I have not managed to find the cause of it, unfortunately

Comment: resolvers code? ... log some, own metrics from resolvers or use a plugin https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/#creating-a-plugin

Comment: I also have the problem that apollo-server has become awfully slow. No Idea what the problem is. which node version are you using?

Comment: In one of my exercises my apollo server need 20 seconds to start,i have only few queries and google OAuth,unacceptable.

Comment: We're having the same issue: wildly varying response times from queries, sometimes ranging from 500ms - 60s. Did you manage to fix your issue?

Comment: @TerryMorgan no, had to drop Apollo